# How to filter a specifc id and then apply jquery

Tags: php, jquery

1. I am passing all ids to the jQuery function. Now i want to apply jQuery only to the  certain ids. Plz help me

   Suppose this function where the id parameter is passed from php onmouseover, its value is ranged from 0 to 100

   ```
   function un(id){   //this id has the ids from 0 to 100 and I only want to apply css effects to the id=33
      //alert(id);
      $('#33').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
   }
   ```
2. If the ids are in an  array how can I pass these ids to the above jQuery function and then how can i use then in selector. Suppose,

   ```
   <?php 
     $children = $this->get_child_nodes2($id);
     echo  implode("", $children);      
   ?>
   ```

Comment: The question is vague, anyway, **a number isn't a valid id**

Comment: ... _if the doctype of the page is not HTML5._

Comment: Basicalli i have results from the database ,i want to apply the  css to the result where id=33.Plz suggest the right approach.

Comment: You need an if statement `if (id === 33) {...} else ...`

Comment: @SidraNaeem, The approach will be to append a particular class(e.g: `class1`) to the required elements. In your case add that class when generating the elements in php, i.e, when elements have the id you require, add that class from server-side itself. And just style the `class1` in css, as required.

Comment: @undefined. But the browser still need to support HTML5, right?

Comment: Why don't you simply add a class to those elements? That seems to be the right way.

Answer (score 2):

Create the string which jQuery uses to search with dynamic:

```
function un(id){   //this id has the ids from 0 to 100 and I only want to apply css effects to the id=33
  //alert(id);
  $('#' + id).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
}
```

Comment: haha good point! edit: but html5 does allow it (I didn't actually know that either)

Comment: Yes, it *is* (but *only* if the doctype is html5).